# What does "(say)" mean in this Java method in Hadoop The Definitive Guide?

Tags: java

What does "(say)" mean in this Java method?

> Since `Mapper` and `Reducer` are separate classes, the type parameters have different scopes, and the actual type argument of `KEYIN` (say) in the `Mapper` may be different from the type of the type parameter of the same name (`KEYIN`) in the `Reducer`.  For instance, in the maximum temperature example from earlier chapters, `KEYIN` in replaced by `longWritaeble` for the `Mapper` and by `Text` for the `Reducer`.

From Hadoop The Definitive Guide, by Tom White, page 224 (scanned version of the page at [223](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tamWg.png) and [224](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHkHj.png)).

Comment: I think that's a typo.  I think it should say `KEYIN(key)` or simply `KEYIN`.  You can probably safely ignore it.

Comment: Good Effort, to scan the page and upload it. Thumbs Up for the Effort.

Comment: Interesting gray area: english.SE or programmers.SE ... not sure which one it really belongs on :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No. It _is_ saying simply `KEYIN`. The "say" is typeset with text font, not symbol font.

Comment: Is it allowed/legal to scan pages from a copy righted materials and post them on the mighty web?

Comment: @chiron: Read up on "Fair Use." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I read that (say) in this case as 'for example', i.e. type parameter of the others could also vary between the Mapper and the Reducer.

So, I'm parsing it to mean that `KEYIN`, `KEYOUT`, `VALUEIN`, `VALUEOUT` could each have different type arguments in the Reducer as compared to their corresponding Mapper arg types.

Answer (score 3):

The use of "say" in the passage is another way of writing "for example" posing a hypothetical.

An example of this usage seen on English.SE - [How to punctuate an example indicated by “say”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67729/how-to-punctuate-an-example-indicated-by-say) which shows "parenthetical commas":

> "If you have (say) a bucket..."

In the paragraph, "For instance" follows this sentence and an editor may find it wordy to use another clause construct that starts with "for".  It is easier to modify the one in the middle of a sentence to "say" rather than the one that starts a sentence.

An identical meaning of the text:

> Since `Mapper` and `Reducer` are separate classes, the type parameters have different scopes, and the actual type argument of `KEYIN`, for example, in the `Mapper` may be different from the type of the type parameter of the same name (`KEYIN`) in the `Reducer`. For instance, in the maximum temperature example from earlier chapters, `KEYIN` in replaced by `longWritaeble` for the `Mapper` and by `Text` for the `Reducer`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no doubt that it is just the usage of the english word 'say' and I don't think it has anything to do with Java.

Comment: Other comments and answers would contradict your answer.  Consider expanding upon your answer to explain why there's `no doubt` about what it _should_ mean.

Comment: @GlenH7 I interpret this answer as a fairly straight-forward, and consistent with the other answers, in short this is just a question about the meaning of a word that is independent of the specific programming language. Am I missing something?